# Multicolored Batch File

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have this batch file i wrote, and i wrote it to make specific words to be different colors, as a test.

But so far, i can't get any farther than this, I'm stuck, and I was wanting to use it to make other words in different colors, to make a color coding scheme. But can't figure out how. I've honestly spent weeks trying to figure this one out but am having no luck.

Here is my code:

```
MD Color
CD Color
cls
echo Cool> "Text to Color"
echo Hello> "Test"
echo Test> "Helloo"
cls
FINDSTR /A:0c /C:"Cool" /S "Text to Color"
FINDSTR /A:0b /C:"Hello" /S "Test"
FINDSTR /A:0a /C:"Test" /S "Helloo"
CD..
RD /S /Q Color
@pause
```

The name of the file is "Text to Color.bat" in a folder named "Color"

Result

```
C:\Users\CST27\Dropbox\Color\Color>FINDSTR /A:0c /C:"Cool" /S "Text to Color"
Text to Color:Cool

C:\Users\CST27\Dropbox\Color\Color>FINDSTR /A:0b /C:"Hello" /S "Test"
Test:Hello

C:\Users\CST27\Dropbox\Color\Color>FINDSTR /A:0a /C:"Test" /S "Helloo"
Helloo:Test

C:\Users\CST27\Dropbox\Color\Color>CD..

C:\Users\CST27\Dropbox\Color>RD /S /Q Color
Press any key to continue . . .
```

With "text to color" in red, "test" in blue, and "Helloo" in green.

And I was wanting to maybe try and make the words after those in a different color as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows PowerShell instead of cmd.exe

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -Object "Hello";
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Blue -Object "World!";
```

Comment: Now, can i make a batch file or some type of file that opens in windows powershell?

Comment: PowerShell commands can be executed in a script, and vice versa. The script contents should be saved to a .ps1 file. There is lots of documentation about how to execute scripts. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx

Comment: Don't give a PS answer when the OP was asking for batch. You wouldn't like that someone answers your java question in pascal, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Just add

> @echo off

and you will get a result like this-

> Text to Color:Cool
>
> Test:Hello
>
> Helloo:Test
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

With "Text to Color:" in red
"Test:" in cyan
and "Helloo:" in green

And I am grateful to you for uploading your code, Thanks bruh.